# How to get the number of peers downloaded the torrent?

Tags: bittorrent, dht

I've got metadata by `bittorrent protocol`, and I want to know how many people downloaded the torrent. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What do you want to do? Do you want to *add* new nodes values to a torrent file?

Comment: @the8472 I want to know How many peers downloaded the torrent

Comment: that has nothing to do with the `nodes` key in the torrent file. `nodes` only serves as a way to bootstrap the DHT.

Comment: @the8472 Then how to get the number of peers  downloaded the torrent ?

Comment: If that's what you actually want to know then you should rewrite your question and provide more details.

Comment: @the8472 I changed the question

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to learn that from the metadata or tracker. There is no counter logic anywhere to count the number of peers downloaded the torrent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the number of clients *currently* downloading a torrent and don't know its tracker URL then you can use [Peer Exchange (BEP11)](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0011.html) to survey the swarm.

The [DHT Scrapes (BEP33)](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0033.html) can give you a rough estimate without connecting to the swarm.